# Flicking Qt application using squish

Tags: qt, squish

Can anyone please help me in understanding how the flick function works when called `flick(objectOrName, x, y, dx, dy, cdx, cdy)` using python. When I tried it, it is not working; it is throwing an error:

```
Cannot call flick with null declarative item
```

Answer (score 0):

1. first lets define this flick, applied on objects: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-flickable.html
2. second, from your error, I only got the feeling that your item, it's not of flickable type. Please go to http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/, and search for flick() .... and you will see that

> ... *It initiates a flick of the specified objectOrName item—which must be a QML Flickable* ...

If you have those things cleared, please send an email to ***contact@froglogic.com***, I'm sure it's more quicker this way.